# Why does this simple LISP function throw an error?

Tags: syntax-error, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I isolated this function from a larger script and ran it through https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-clisp-online/. Even though there is an error thrown, it seems to follow the rules of LISP unless I'm missing something blatantly obvious.

```
(defun cannibals-can-eat (state start-state)
    (let ((left-bank-missionaries 2)
         (left-bank-cannibals 5)
         (right-bank-missionaries (- 3 left-bank-missionaries))
         (right-bank-cannibals (- 2 left-bank-cannibals)))

         (if (or (> left-bank-cannibals left-bank-missionaries)
                 (> right-bank-cannibals right-bank-missionaries))
             t
             nil)))
```

The error is sometimes `The variable LEFT-BANK-MISSIONARIES is unbound.unmatched close parenthesis` or `syntax error near unexpected token`('`. With this version of the function the error is the latter.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the `let` function won't let you use a variable that you declared to declare another variable even if it's subsequent.

Comment: You might want to read on `let` vs `let*`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Common Lisp there are two forms of local declarations (`let`):

```
(let ((var1 exp1)
      (var2 exp2)
      ...
      (varn expn))
  exp)
```

and

```
(let* ((var1 exp1)
       (var2 exp2)
       ...
       (varn expn))
  exp)
```

In the first every expression `expi` is evaluated in the environment holding before the `let`. In the second every expression `expi` is evaluated in the environment containing all the previous declarations `var1 ... var(i-1)`.

So in your example the declaration of `right-bank-missionaries` uses `left-bank-missionaries` which is undefined since it is declared in the same `let`.

Simply use `let*` to allow the use of every variable immediately after its declaration:

```
(defun cannibals-can-eat (state start-state)
    (let* ((left-bank-missionaries 2)
           (left-bank-cannibals 5)
           (right-bank-missionaries (- 3 left-bank-missionaries))
           (right-bank-cannibals (- 2 left-bank-cannibals)))

      (or (> left-bank-cannibals left-bank-missionaries)
          (> right-bank-cannibals right-bank-missionaries))))
```

Note that the final `if` is useless if you want to return a [generalized boolean](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_g.htm).